# Query returns cartesian product (Northwind)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, northwind

[image]

I am using ***northwind*** database in oracle.

**Task :**
Fetch no. of employees working in each region.

**Result:**
(RegionName, No. of employees)

I am trying this query but it return cartesian product

```
select r.regiondescription, count(e.employeeid)
from employees e,
     employeeterritories et,
     territories t,
     region r 
where r.regionid = t.regionid
  and et.territoryid = t.territoryid
  and e.employeeid = et.employeeid
group by r.regiondescription;
```

**Question:** What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Cartesian product between which tables? And do you mean it is returning a cartesian product before doing a group by? Can you post a sample of data and the result you are getting now and what you are expecting?

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with that query. (Well, you should use modern, explicit JOIN syntax instead of that old implicit join syntax...)

Comment: check it i have uploaded

Comment: How many employees in your tables?

Comment: You have specified 4 tables, but there are only 3 tables joined. You need to add employeeterritories to the where clause.

Comment: Yes I add 'et.territoryid = t.territoryid'

Comment: @rontornambe its already in the where clause, twice!

Comment: Which version of Office are you using? I do have Northwind in access 2007 but cannot see employeeterritories, territories and region tables. Did you create them?

Comment: I am using oracle 11 g express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is that one of your table is multiplying results, and you should use count(DISTINCT) instead:

```
select r.regiondescription, count(distinct e.employeeid)
from employees e,
     employeeterritories et,
     territories t,
     region r 
where r.regionid = t.regionid
  and et.territoryid = t.territoryid
  and e.employeeid = et.employeeid
group by r.regiondescription;
```

Comment: Why it returns cartesian product can you explain it ?

Comment: What do you mean by cartesian ? Multiplied?

Comment: Yes i mean multiplied

Comment: @nafeesahmed If one of the tables contains more then 1 record for the relation mentioned (regionId / territoryId/empId) each row will be multiplied by the count of the records for this unique ID

Comment: The other thing that is wrong with the query (but probably not something OP is looking for) is the lack of outer joins in case there are regions or territories without any employees. The problem statement to show all regions with a count of employees in them would leave out those regions otherwise.

Comment: Another problem is the use of implicit join syntax , there are plenty:) @ruudvan